# check session endpoint enabled but session id is missing

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

Can anybody elaborate me how to I can disable session endpoint or where I can provision correct session id?
This error is in the `IdenttyServer4` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` that I use?
I this this is not related to my client. I have an installed version of `IdenityServer4 (1.5.X)` and the client works fine with that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are authenticated in IdSrv, but your idsrv.session cookie missed. That might happen when you override the auth cookie for the IdSrv host, but keep the session cookie unchanged. In your `ConfigureServices` look for:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
.AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources())
...

services.AddAuthentication("MyCookie")
.AddCookie("MyCookie", options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = ...;
});
```

and just remove `services.AddAuthentication()` and `.AddCookie()` if you are not absalutely sure you need them.